# Invariance of Permanent of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, permanent

It is well known that the determinant of a matrix is invariant under some operations such as taking its transpose or row and column operations. Are there similar operations which fix the permanent of a matrix?

Answer (score 5):

In general *immanants* (which include permanents as a special case) are invariant under conjugation by any permutation matrix.

For an $n\times n$ matrix $M$, this follows from the definition of the immanant:
\begin{align}
\hbox{Imm}^{\lambda}(M)&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\chi^{\lambda}(\sigma)P_{\sigma}
\left[M_{11}M_{22}\ldots M_{nn}\right]\, ,\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\chi^{\lambda}(\sigma)
\left[M_{1\sigma(1)}M_{2\sigma(2)}\ldots M_{n\sigma(n)}\right]\, ,
\end{align}
where $\chi^{\lambda}(\sigma)$ is the character of element $\sigma$ in the irrep $\lambda$.

Conjugation by a permutation simply shuffles the ordering of the terms in the sum of elements in (1), but since all elements in the same class have the same character the sum itself remains invariant.

Minc has studied the more general problem in what types of linear transformations preserve the permanent (and other properties) in

> Henryk Minc (1976) The invariance of elementary symmetric functions, Linear
>   and Multilinear Algebra, 4:3, 209-215

Answer (score 1):

The transpose does. Just stare at the formula.

Comment: So does swapping rows or columns.  But other row operations like subtracting one row from another must have some effect on the permanent/  Otherwise one could use those operations to reduce a matrix to a triangular one, whose permanent is thus equal to the determinant.  This contradicts Valiant's theorem on the difficulty of computing the permanent (unless of course #P = NP = P).